# If entered word is found in worksheet, then excute A, if not found, then excute B

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to write a macro that if I enter a 3-letter month abbreviation and it's found in working sheet, A will be executed; else (if not found), then let a message box pop up ("What you entered doesn't match anything").

Below is my code. It works well when there's a match, but when there's no match or a wrong-typed 3-letter word, then there's a debug message - **`" Run time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"`**.

The line that triggers the error is:

```
 If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=FindMonth, _
 LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column <> "0" Then
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with it? How can I fix the error? Thank you.

---

```
Sub CDAEnter()
Dim RwcRow As Integer
Dim MSColumn1 As Integer
Dim MSColumn2 As Integer
Dim MSColumn3 As Integer
Dim MSColumn4 As Integer
Dim PDRRow1 As Integer
Dim PDRRow2 As Integer
Dim PDRRow3 As Integer
Dim PDRRow4 As Integer

Dim MColumn As Integer
Dim FindMonth As String

RwcRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(what:="RWC").Row

MSColumn1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(what:="ABC").Column

MSColumn2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(what:="DEF").Column

MSColumn3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(what:="GHI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

MSColumn4 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(what:="JKL").Column

PDRRow1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="MNO").Row
PDRRow2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="PQR").Row
PDRRow3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="STU").Row
PDRRow4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:="VWX").Row

FindMonth = InputBox("Enter 3-letter Working Month ")

If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=FindMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column <> "0" Then

MColumn = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=FindMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RwcRow, MSColumn1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(PDRRow1, MColumn)

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RwcRow, MSColumn2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(PDRRow2, MColumn)

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RwcRow, MSColumn3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(PDRRow3, MColumn)

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RwcRow, MSColumn4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(PDRRow4, MColumn)

Exit Sub

ElseIf IsError(MColumn) = True Then MsgBox "What you entered doesn't match anything"
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by declaring all your variables, ie Dim variableA As String, Dim variableB as Integer

Comment: Which line of code triggers the error?

Comment: I would also add option explicit at the top to force all variables to be defined. It will also help you catch mistyped variables.

Comment: The below line triggers the error.

    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=FindMonth, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column <> "0" Then

Comment: `Find()` returns `Nothing` if no match is located.  You need to test the return value using `Is Nothing` before trying to access the `Column` property

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the comments, I'll post it as answer (I know you guys maybe too busy to post the answer).
Should any of them decide to post their comment as answer, then I'll delete mine.

First declare a variable:

```
Dim r As Range ' Find method returns a range object, so you'll need a variable to hold it

Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(what:=FindMonth, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole) 
        'I just copied above from your IF statement since you said it works
```

As Tim mentioned, check if you found something:

```
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    'You put the rest of your code here
Else
    MsgBox "What you entered doesn't match anything.", vbInformation
    'Inform the user through a message box
End If
```

If you still have problems, in your attempts, please add comment or revise your question.
If it is entirely different issue, post another.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out! It works well completely. Appreciately it.